# Calculating the percentile of a value based on data in another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I let's supposed I have two pandas dataframes.

```
Month   Half    Value
Jan       1      15
Feb       2      80
```

And a second table that has a huge amount of values that I've simplified here but are a historical distribution of the "Value" data by Month and Half.

```
Month   Half    Value
Jan      1       10
Jan      1       20
Jan      1       45
Jan      2       30
Jan      2       50
Jan      2       75
Feb      1       15
Feb      1       25
Feb      1       45
Feb      2       45
Feb      2       70
Feb      2       85
```

I am trying to create a new column in the first table that takes the Value in the first table and looks up where it sits in the second table by way of its percentile position for its given Month and Half.

So we would return a table something like (percentiles are just indicative here):

```
Month   Half    Value   Percentile
Jan       1      15         14
Feb       2      80         93
```

Where for the first row, the value of 15 for the Month of Jan and the Half=1, sits at the 14th percentile of those values with Month=Jan and Half=1 in the second table.

I hope I've explained this clearly enough!

Comment: Don't understand how 14th is calculated.

Comment: This is what I want to calculate - the 14 here is where the value 15 sits as a percentile in the other table relative to all the values in that table that have Month=Jan and Half=1

Comment: I don't understand how the percentile is calculated, 15/(10+20+45) is 0.2.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh that is not how percentiles are calculated... They are the percent of data that is smaller than the target!

Comment: I've edited the text above to say that the percentiles in this chart are indicative and the 2nd table is a very large table so I'm not looking replicate these numbers exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the percentile of a value using `scipy.stat.percentileofscore`. You then only need to group the big dataframe by *Month* and *Half* and then for each row of the small dataframe get the group of the big one corresponding to that month and half and calculate the percentile of value:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Month": ["Jan", "Feb"], "Half": [1, 2], "Value": [15, 80]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Month": [
            "Jan",
            "Jan",
            "Jan",
            "Jan",
            "Jan",
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Feb",
            "Feb",
            "Feb",
            "Feb",
            "Feb",
        ],
        "Half": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "Value": [10, 20, 45, 30, 50, 75, 15, 25, 45, 45, 70, 85],
    }
)

groups = df2.groupby(["Month", "Half"])
df1["Percentile"] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: percentileofscore(
        groups.get_group((row["Month"], row["Half"]))["Value"], row["Value"]
    ),
    axis=1,
)
print(df1)
```

Comment: Belatedly - thank you - worked a treat.